# Is it a 'breaking change' (per semver) if a build tool forces re-build?

Tags: semantic-versioning

There's a build tool that exposes two functions kind of like this (simplifying a bit):

```
build(buildSpec): BuildResult;
getBuildStatus(buildSpec): 'ok' | 'needsRebuild';
```

There are often improvements to the build process that don't affect the signatures above or how the user is expected to use the tool.
However, we want to force rebuilding in those cases, so that users can get the improvements.

So the following happens:

- user builds
- user checks the status and sees 'ok'
- user upgrades the tool
- users checks the status and sees 'needsRebuild'

Is *every* upgrade then a 'breaking change'? That is, does the semantic versioning ["spec"](https://semver.org/#spec-item-8) specify in enough detail it has an opinion on whether 'not saying previous builds are OK is a change in public API' is true?

I'm concerned about this, as it is really uncool these days to not be fully semver-styles, but it would also be really uncool if an extreme change like **modifying the function signatures in a backwards-incompatible way** were lost in our changelog in a see of major version increments for every bug fix and feature addition.